Conditional labeling vertices in a graph's connected component - igraph R
I have a connected component in a graph and I need to convert it into a data frame. Each vertex should be assigned a unique label based on its position or path within the graph. For instance, vertices A1 to A3 should share the label A, and vertices C1 to C3 should share the label C. The criteria for labelling is that the path terminates either before a vertex with two incoming edges or at a vertex with two outgoing edges. The images also the expected number of labels, i.e., 7.

A reproducible example:
library(igraph)

df <- structure(list(from = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B1", "B2", "B3", 
"C1", "C2", "C3", "E1", "E2", "E3", "F1", "F2", "D1", "E3", "G1", 
"G2", "G3"), to = c("A2", "A3", "A4", "C1", "B2", "B3", "C1", 
"C2", "C3", "D1", "E2", "E3", "F1", "F2", "D1", "D2", "G1", "G2", 
"G3", "G4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
plot(g)


I thought about using degreeand counting the edges for each vertex. However, I still don't know the paths (I'm newbie to using igraph).

I think you pain point is to find a way that could set breakpoints to split the entire graph into multiple subgraphs, according to the in/out-degree of vertices.
We can think of the question in another way: Can we remove the in/out-wards edges to a vertex if that vertex has more than 1 in/out-wards edges? If we can do that, the graph can be decomposed as requested.

You can try the code below
df %>%
    filter(n() == 1, .by = to) %>%
    filter(n() == 1, .by = from) %>%
    graph_from_data_frame() %>%
    decompose()

where

filter(n() == 1, .by = to) is to keep the vertices (associated with edges) with 1 inwards neighbor
filter(n() == 1, .by = from) is to keep the vertices (associated with edges) with 1 outwards neighbor.


You will obtain the the exclusive groups as desired
[[1]]
IGRAPH 3d01e52 DN-- 4 3 --
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges from 3d01e52 (vertex names):
[1] A1->A2 A2->A3 A3->A4

[[2]]
IGRAPH 3d01e85 DN-- 3 2 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges from 3d01e85 (vertex names):
[1] B1->B2 B2->B3

[[3]]
IGRAPH 3d01eac DN-- 3 2 --
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges from 3d01eac (vertex names):
[1] C1->C2 C2->C3

[[4]]
IGRAPH 3d01ed6 DN-- 3 2 --
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges from 3d01ed6 (vertex names):
[1] E1->E2 E2->E3

[[5]]
IGRAPH 3d01f00 DN-- 2 1 --
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edge from 3d01f00 (vertex names):
[1] F1->F2

[[6]]
IGRAPH 3d01f29 DN-- 2 1 --
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edge from 3d01f29 (vertex names):
[1] D1->D2

[[7]]
IGRAPH 3d01f4f DN-- 4 3 --
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges from 3d01f4f (vertex names):
[1] G1->G2 G2->G3 G3->G4

and the graph looks like

